# Assign nil to NSString within Autorelease pool

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsstring

I'm making a great deal of NSString manipulations within an autorelease pool. Problem is my program will sometimes crash before the pool drains. I'm wondering if there is a way to circumvent this problem by assigning nil to NSString. The assignment to userLetters happens a lot. See code below

**Before**

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   usersLetters = [usersLetters stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(indexUser, 1) withString:@"*"];
[pool drain];
```

**After**

```
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   NSString *temp = [usersLetters stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(indexUser, 1) withString:@"*"]; //remove that found character so it can't be reused again
   usersLetters = nil;
   usersLetters = temp;
   temp = nil;
[pool drain];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt what assigning to nil will help in what you want to achieve. 
(I assume you mean that your program crashes because the memory is exhausted, otherwise, it is much more likely that you released to often somewhere, you should also run the Status Analyzer over your code.)

What you can do is to send a retain message to all objects that you still need (in your case usersLetters) and drain the pool afterwards. The objects that you still need should then have a retain count of 1, all other autoreleased objects should have been deallocated.

In your case, this would be

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
usersLetters = [[usersLetters stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(indexUser, 1) withString:@"*"] retain]; //sending retain to an object increases its retain count by 1 and returns the object itself
// some more stuff that needs memory
[pool drain];
// ...
[usersLetters release];
[pool release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if your project targets iOS or Mac OS X. If the latter, the best way to resolve this issue may be to simply use garbage collection.

If GC is not an option (which it is not on iOS), the idiomatic way to deal with this is to wrap a nested autorelease pool around your inner, fast-allocating operations. In this case you must retain any objects which need to outlive the nested pool, as mrueg has explained.